# What does ForbiddenContext.Fail() do?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

When setting up my `JwtBearerEvents` there is an event called `OnForbidden`.  That passes an object of type `ForbiddenContext`.  `ForbiddenContext` has a method on it called `Fail()`:

```
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
{
    // Other stuff here

    OnForbidden = context =>
    {
        context.Fail("Bad Stuff");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

};
```

The help for that method says:

> Indicates that there was a failure during authentication.

But calling that method has no effect on the output of my application.

For my application, if I don't pass the tests in my custom `IAuthorizationRequirement` then a 403 is returned.  As I said above, if I call `ForbiddenContext.Fail()` then the result is the same (a 403 with an empty body).

**So, I am left wondering, what is the expected use of `ForbiddenContext.Fail()`?**

Answer (score 1):

The value will be saved to [AuthenticateResult.Failure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticateresult.failure?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_AuthenticateResult_Failure). If we want to get the output or know how to use.

Following is the demo code:

```
return context.Response.WriteAsync(
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ProjectResponse 
{ 
    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, 
    Message = context.Result.Failure.Message }
));
```